# Select columns before join vs after join

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I was wondering if it makes a difference to select the relevant columns before or after I join two (or ten...) tables on the basis of performance.

Let's say each table (A / B) has 20-30 columns originally.

Example1:

```
SELECT A.col1, A.col2, B.col3, B.col4
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.col2 = A.col2
```

Example2:

```
SELECT A.col1, A.col2, B.col3, B.col4
FROM (SELECT col1, col2 FROM A) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT col2, col3, col4 FROM B) B ON (B.col2 = A.col2)
```

Is there a difference in performance?

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you?

Comment: Any dbms should optimize that. Do version 1 to keep the code simple, skip those subqueries.

Comment: I ended up using the second example with a SELECT DISTINCT - not because of performance per se, but because with a 78GB table, I got a disc error. I'm guessing it depends on the ability of the optimizer which is faster (?), but for my specific case there was also the storage factor as it turns out.

Comment: What kind of disc error? You used a DISTINCT even if you didnt need it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Well, if you apply a `DISTINCT` to one of the derived tables, that's a completely different query.

Comment: Error was [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Disk Full, code 1016 -- I'm running a redshift. Without the distinct it would "crash". Weirdly with it it works now.

Comment: That means your query returns duplicates, which probably means your join condition is incomplete (it produces a partial Cartesian product).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any modern optimizer will treat the two queries as identical. So for the sake of readability use the first one.

Online examples for:

[Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7c697233c709c99bc121dd5bfe0186fd)

```
Hash Right Join  (cost=17.20..31.12 rows=320 width=444)
  Hash Cond: (b.col2 = a.col1)
  ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..13.10 rows=310 width=226)
  ->  Hash  (cost=13.20..13.20 rows=320 width=222)
        ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..13.20 rows=320 width=222)
```

---

[Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c9cbc1ce5e7deb8c4b825fcc0e97f478)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     5 |   715 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER   |      |     5 |   715 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     3 |   195 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |     5 |   390 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

[SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d70b5f99f13112ff46b6444787247457) - there the two plans are actually slightly different but the general approach is identical

[image]

[image]

Not sure what the "compute scalar" is doing there (I have very limited experience with SQL Server) but the cost seems to indicate that it doesn't really change anything.

---

MySQL also generates exactly the same plans (DbFiddle won't let me run explain for MySQL)

```
id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra                                             
---+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----+---------+-----+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------
 1 | SIMPLE      | A     |            | ALL  |               |     |         |     |    3 |      100 |                                                   
 1 | SIMPLE      | B     |            | ALL  |               |     |         |     |    5 |      100 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the second Example will be slower , as you have written a subquery , so the execution plan will be longer , first for the select inside the subquery than the outer Select.
You are querying it twice. First Example is the right way to do it.

Comment: That's plain wrong for any modern DBMS - both will produce exactly the execution plan